# TS2339: Property 'DisplayNames' does not exist on type 'typeof Intl'

Tags: typescript, intl

How can i fix that type error?
TS2339: Property 'DisplayNames' does not exist on type 'typeof Intl'.

my function:

```
export const getLanguageName = (locale: string | null) => {
  const localeName = new Intl.DisplayNames([locale], { type: 'language' });
  return localeName.of(locale);
};
```

Comment: what's your environment? (browser or Node.js? serverless?)

Comment: Browser........

Answer (score 2):

If you arrived here looking for an Angular solution, I think it's safe to just use `target: "es2020"` and update your library declarations in your tsconfig.base.ts (at the root level)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
            ...
            "target": "es2020",
            "lib": ["dom", "es2020"]
    }
}
```

That should give you access to the new Intl API types definitions removing the errors from your editor and also any possible compilation errors.
A few years ago we could only use es2015 due to some [issues with async/await and zone.js](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18162) but this was [addressed](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/19871) in 2021.

Answer (score 0):

[It's still missing in TypeScript for now](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41338#issuecomment-1257926423)

You can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to make the types available in your code base, or you can make a TypeScript PR

---

Also, make sure the targeted browsers support this: https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_displaynames_of

Or you might need a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill):

- If you want to include it in your bundle: https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-displaynames/
- If you want to load it directly from a UA-sniffer CDN: https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.DisplayNames
  (see [builder](https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder/))